# Add code in a completion block parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, exc-bad-access

Sorry if this question has already been asked. I can't find good keywords to have an answer...

In a completion block, is it possible to add code before or after a block variable?

I would like to do something like this:

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion {
    [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:^{
        //some code I add here
        completion();
    }];
}
```

I have a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I try to do this.

**EDIT: Issue is caused by the use of "completion()" without checking if it could be nil or not.**

Comment: Oh I think I get this. Maybe I have to check if "completion" isn't nil in first place? It is working if I do so?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What do you mean by "add code in a completion block variable"?

Comment: Yes @Tulleb, you must check for nil before invoking the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can add code where you have your comment. Your crash is caused by some other problem, like an un-initialized variable, or perhaps you are using a local variable that has gone out of scope.